# Copy the gallery photo into my app's folder

Tags: java, android

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

```
//activity A intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,null);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent,Constant.ACTION.LOAD_GALLERY_ACTION);

//this is onActicityResult function
case Constant.ACTION.LOAD_GALLERY_ACTION:
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if(mImage.size()<maxAddPic) {
                mImage.add(copyGalleryPic(uri));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;

//to copy the gallery photo,return the new file uri.
private Uri copyGalleryPic(Uri uri) {

    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/"+"diary"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
    File outputFile = new File(filePath);
    if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
        outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {

        bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ... handle IO exception
    }
    Uri newUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(CreateDiaryActivity.this,"com.example.diary.cr",outputFile);
    return newUri;
}
```

but there are some errors

the intent returns uri

> "content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F29/ORIGINAL/NONE/41130179"

but debug  info shows the code

> "**bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),
>   uri);**"  error : *java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT
>   (No such file or directory)*

please help me !  Love you guys!

My English is not well. please use Simple words. Thank you!

Comment: Have you requested runtime permission?

Comment: Thank you. I found the answer that Android Studio maybe have some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

- which android version and which sdk-version are you using? I have an android-2.2 app that cannot receive intent permissions under android 7 see: https://github.com/k3b/intent-intercept/issues/4. I assume that recompiling with a more recent android-sdk might help.
- Does you program work if you use an InputStream to read the picked image via [getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData(uri))](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)).
- Since android-4.4 ACTION_PICK was replaced by ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. My recent apps that use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT together with openInputStream work as expected

Comment: Thank you. After I posted the question, I didn't change anything code. But Now those codes WORK WELL. I don't know what's happened.